# Printing metal infused PLA does not work well

Tags: pla, filament, filled-pla

I have a 3D printer and I want to 3D print with metal infused PLA filament. It seems that this filament does not print that well (it won't melt to the right consistency). I referred to my manual and it does not talk about plastic or metal filaments. Is using metal causing the problem or is it something else.

The printer I have is a JGMAKER Magic 3D Printer DIY Kit with Filament Run Out Detection Sensor and Resume Print Metal Base 3D Printers for Hobbyist Education.

I am printing [these Christmas balls](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5129377)  in different colors for the holidays.

The metal filament is Silk Copper 3D Printer Filament PLA (1.75 mm) Shine Silky Shiny Copper Like PLA CC3D ZHUOPU

Comment: Maybe you should do images of the prints and add more info on the slicing parameters like e.g. temperature, speed, cooling, etc.

Comment: It won't print its consistency is like honey. The temperature is also the same as plastic filament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is is PLA, and if you can print regular PLA then this metalised one should print too.  However if its a different brand then you may need to increase the hotend temperature in small steps.

I'd suggest you load the filament, and then turn on the heaters to bring it all up to temp.  Then use the extruder feedingn knob to force some filament into the hotend.  It should come out like hot cheese, and if not then increase the hotend temp till it does.

In your slicer, it should be possible to set up a profile for this material with settings it likes, to ease future printing.

---

Your comment say it drips, which suggests the hotend temp is too HIGH and the plastic is liquifying.  Start at 140 degrees C and then work up from there, not down.

Comment: alternatively you could print a temperature tower.